# On Premise Sharepoint Server incoming email setup with O365 Exchange Online

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, exchange-online

We want to use incoming email feature for an on-premise Sharepoint Server that does not have internet connection. If I want to configure sharepoint to receive email from O365, what architecture should I adopt and any documented steps?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server X between Office 365 and SharePoint.

- X must have access to internet, but you can of course limit it using firewall not to be open to anything else except receiging mail from Exchange Online.
- On X you'd install SMTP Server that can receive email from Exchange Online.
- Received email will end up in the Drop folder on server X. From there you need to move the files to the SharePoint server by some means (robocopy perhaps).
- The rest is configuring SharePoint for incoming email as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx). For the drop folder in SharePoint configuration you'd define the folder where you copy the files from server X. I haven't tested, but you may even be able to configure the drop folder in SharePoint to directly fetch them from file share on server X.